Getting Delay of 10 ms in threaded IRQ handler execution
I have written the device driver in the Linux platform. I have below requirements for that specific driver.

Detect the rising edge and falling edge interrupt on one GPIO pin.
perform the i2c reading from another sensor(on rising edge detection).
on falling edge perform small execution for time calcution.

For interrupt detection (rising / falling), I have registered the Threaded IRQ as shown below.
result = request_threaded_irq(irqNumber, (void *)r_irq_handler, irq_interrupt_thread_fn, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING | IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING, "irqHandler", NULL);

Here, at every 50 ms, we are getting one interrupt on this GPIO. The pulse width of this interrupt signal is 10ms. So at every 50ms, the IRQ handler will be executed 2 times. One time for the rising edge and after 10ms it will execute that IRQ handler for the falling edge.
So while testing the implementation, I came across to a few unexpected behaviours of IRQ handler, which are described shown below.

I am using the stress command to load the CPU cores (stress --cpu 6) and perform the long run. I found a few observations in which IRQ handler took 7-10 ms to execute the top half.

while loading the system few miliseconds or microsecond delay is expected but can it really go up to 10ms like this? Or have any errors been happening in my implementation?


Note:
In IRQ handler we are just using ktime() function to register the event time and setting one flag based on the rising edge/falling edge.
Has anyone come across such an issue in Linux threaded IRQ implementation? Is there any workaround for this issue?
I'm facing irregularities in the IRQ handler execution in long run of 12 hours, 24 hours like that. and in short time it is not coming (half hour test).
